# jquery variable comparison with previously assigned variable resulting false

Tags: jquery, comparison

I have a link `<a id="clickMe" href="#">click me</a>` my page in page

and below is the click event associated with that link:

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    var obj=$(this);
    alert(obj==$(this));
});
```

I wonder that this comparison alerting false after assigning **$(this)** to a variable **obj**.  Anybody know the reason for this?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fj5V/5/

Answer (score 2):

Because every call to `$()` creates a new jQuery wrapper object.

See the `Not All jQuery Objects are Created` section in [jQuery Object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)